# Find area between $y=\frac1x,y=x,x=e$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have to calculate area between the 3 curves:
$$y=\frac1x\quad y=x\quad x=e$$
I integrated $(x-1/x$) from 1 to $e$, but it does not match any option. The given answer was $\frac32$.

Can you explain the the approach?

Comment: The book is wrong.

Comment: you mean 3/2 isn't the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, the correct area is $\int_1^e(x-\frac{1}{x})\,dx$ if the text you reported is right: the three curves delimit a well determined bounded region that can be clearly seen in the picture in A.k.'s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y=1/x$ bounds the region from *above* and the $x$-axis is implied to bound the region from below, the given answer is obtained:
$$\int_0^1x\,dx+\int_1^e\frac1x\,dx=\left[\frac{x^2}2\right]_0^1+[\ln x]_1^e=\left(\frac12-0\right)+(1-0)=\frac32$$
If $y=1/x$ bounds the region from below, leaving no implicit boundaries, a different answer is obtained:
$$\int_1^e\left(x-\frac1x\right)\,dx=\left[\frac{x^2}2-\ln x\right]_1^e=\left(\frac{e^2}2-1\right)-\left(\frac12-0\right)=\frac{e^2-3}2$$
Good questions never leave anything to the reader to interpret, though. As egreg pointed out, the second answer has fewer assumptions and is the correct one.

Comment: I got the same answer, but the correct answer is not this.

Comment: Can you please ignore my integral and rather confirm if you reach the same integral, as a fresh approach?

Comment: should i include area from 0 to 1 also as suggested by other answer?

Comment: 3/2 is the correct option but i am not convinced to use x axis as a boundary

Comment: Leaving aside this quesiton, in general , there should not be any implied boundaries correct?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Why should the axes be implied boundaries? The three curves in the question delimit a unique bounded region, whose area is $(e^2-3)/2$. The answer $3/2$ is simply wrong.

Comment: @egreg I was sure axis are not to be included as boudaries, however Parcly confirmed the opposite.

Comment: Never mind, selected the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 parts

from 0 to 1

&

from 1 to e

try to calculate the area between x  and the x-axis

then between 1/x  and x-axis

[image: Graph of the Area]

Comment: why 0 to 1 also?

Comment: i think x axis is not to be included unless specified

Comment: see the graph of the three curves

Comment: you are also including x=0 as one of the curves, although it is not mentioned in the question

Comment: Your picture clearly shows what is the area between the three curves, which isn't what you compute.